# pyenv global command doesn't set the correct python version

Tags: python, python-3.x, zsh, pyenv, virtual-environment

So I activated this virutal environment:

```
pyenv install 3.7.4
pyenv virtualenv 3.7.4 apps3
pyenv local apps3
pyenv activate apps3
```

and also set this:

```
pyenv global 3.7.4
```

I already have these in my .zshrc profile as suggested here:

```
$ export PATH="$HOME/.pyenv/bin:$PATH"
$ eval "$(pyenv init -)"
$ eval "$(pyenv virtualenv-init -)"
```

However, even then, when I activate the `apps3`and check for `python --version`, I keep getting `Python 2.7.16`, which is the default Python of my system. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 8):

Apparently Pyenv did change the behavior of manipulating the path.

Change the line in your .zshrc from

```
eval "$(pyenv init -)"
```

to

```
eval "$(pyenv init --path)"
```

Then resource your .zshrc and retry.

My sources for this are:
https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv-virtualenv/issues/401#issuecomment-903635119
and
https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv/issues/1649#issuecomment-694388530

(This is my first post on stackoverflow. I apologize if this is not up to the standards and am more than willing to learn if you give me pointers. Thanks)